# Subresource Integrity Opera Browser Support?

Tags: browser, opera, subresource-integrity

Why is Opera SRI support unknown? On a [Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity), it shows various browsers and if they support SRI.  Opera is unknown, why is Opera unknown? Is there not a way of testing Opera, for SRI support?

Comment: According to a [4th November 2015 revision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity$compare?to=946237&from=945979) of the MDN page, Opera 32 supports SRI and Opera Mobile does not. See also [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity) on SRI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a way to test Subresource Integrity support in opera. You just need two things for that, first you need to have opera installed, and second you need some time to start opera, trying to visit a page which should fail the integrity check (possibly setting it up first) to document the result.

It just seems the author of the Wiki entry decided to not spend time on downloading, installing or testing Opera hisself. As it's a Wiki, anyone willing to spend the time on testing opera is likely welcome to add the result.